# g++ can't compile

Tags: g++

```
make[2]: /usr/bin/g++-5: Command not found
CMakeFiles/uwlib.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/uwlib.dir/src/EvoLogics/command.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/uwlib.dir/src/EvoLogics/command.cpp.o] Error 127
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/uwlib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/uwlib.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can't solve this problem. I tried to remove `g++` and install it again, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you installed `build-essential`? If not, open a terminal and run `sudo apt install build-essential`.

Comment: I had and says I already have the newest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/usr/bin/g++-5` file is provided by g++-5 in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install g++-5
```

Please comment if you are using 19.04, so that I can add the instructions for installing the g++-5 package from 18.10.